# How to inherit addActionListener to custom object?

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 classes, one is an instanceof JPanel (called xContain) and the other isn't extending anything (called xShape). There is way too much code to paste here and I don't want to be spoon fed, so I'm going to carefully explain it.

I'm trying to call .addActionListener() on an instance of my xShape. However, it won't work since it doesn't have that method. However, this works when I do it to an instance of JButton or Timer object and I found out that's because the method is inherited from class javax.swing.AbstractButton.

What do I have to inherit to my xShape class so I can add an action listener to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is supposed to work as a button or menu (as @HovercraftFullOfEels mentioned), then you can declare your class to inherit from `AbstractButton`:

```
public class Test extends AbstractButton
```

and override the `addActionListener` method:

```
@Override
public void addActionListener(ActionListener l)
{
    super.addActionListener(l);
    // ...
}
```

**Edit:**

The imports you need are:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;    
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
```

Comment: `import javax.swing.AbstractButton;` Your IDE should do this, are you using any IDE?

Comment: My getSize method return type is being interfered with, with this code. I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: In Eclipse you auto-import with Ctrl + Shift + O. What happens is that `AbstractButton` also have a `getSize()` method which returns a `Dimension` object. You can @Override this method and return a `Dimension` or just change the name of your method.

Comment: Great thanks. It's unfortunate that the getSize() method causes so much grief.

Answer (score 1):

ActionListeners are for button and menu type objects. If your class is neither of these, then don't try to force a square peg into a round hole.

Instead consider using a MouseListener, not an ActionListener, adding the MouseListener to the container that is displaying your XShape, and make sure that your XShape class has a `contains(Point p)` method. This way you can have objects of the type check if button press points are contained within them, and thus react.

Comment: XShape shouldn't be a JComponent or have a JComponent as a property and then delegates its actionListener?

Comment: @nachokk: I never said that it should, but it can certainly implement Shape. It of course needs to be displayed in a JComponent, and that is what gets the MouseListener.